# Can changing internal URLs and implementing redirects risk an SEO penalty from Google?

Tags: seo, google, domains, url

I have the profiles of my website users indexed on Google:

`example.com/username`

I want change profile URLs to:

`example.com/profile/username/id`

All the previous indexed profiles redirect to new link.

Is this change likely to result in  some type of penalty or not? In general is this type of change bad or good for SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, there is no any penalty, nor it is bad for SEO if you done [301 redirection](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) properly**. Website is like house, we often change our furniture and design.

In past Google was using `Google.com/support/` for their product help articles, and now they are using `support.google.com`.

Comment: I would agree, but there is a small loss in link power with redirecting with 301. See Moz article here: https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection.

Comment: In past Google see 301 redirection page as one webpage with one link. So moz said about that link power loss, because that webpage will kept some pagerank, but I think now Google is more smarter, so that webpage(On 301 applied) will kept only negligible PR/reputation.

Comment: Do you have any backup for that claim? All I have seen from personal experience is that there is indeed a small loss. Only exception I have seen so far has been if 301'ing from http to https.

Comment: I have implemented several internal URL changes with 301 redirection successfully.     When done correctly, there should be no loss in rankings.    Any link juice lost in redirects doesn't seem to hurt.

Comment: I have implemented 301 redirection in my website and when I check my position from Google search console, then there is no any difference in position. When we talk about PR, then we should know that we have don't much PR to lose. Most of webpages are ranked because of their content.